# Make outline of a image thicker

Tags: image-processing

I import a jpg image in my notebook. The result is like this:

[image]

I'm interested in the outline so I wrote this code:
ColorNegate[
 EdgeDetect[ColorNegate[AlphaChannel[RemoveBackground[test]]]]]

The result is:

[image]

The outline is 1 pixel. I want to make the outline thicker, for example 2 pixels. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `Dilation` for this.

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp3Ci.jpg"];

edges = EdgeDetect[AlphaChannel[RemoveBackground[im]]];

thickerEdges = Dilation[edges, 5]
```

[image: this shows the bicycle edges after Dilation is applied]