# Adding contour to images

Tags: image-processing, image

I intend to optimize my work by adding an outline to my images automatically.

I'm leaving this image as a reference for testing:

[image]

I can make an outline of the image, but with poor quality ...

```
ColorNegate[EdgeDetect[AlphaChannel[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvtRV.png"]],2,0.07,Method->"Canny"]]
```

I intend to achieve this result by combining the original image with the outline:

[image]

Comment: See this related question and answer [(195840)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195840/make-outline-of-a-image-thicker?rq=1) where `Dilation` can thicken the `EdgeDetect` result.

Answer (score 5):

```
thickness = 10;
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvtRV.png"];
```

**1.** `ContourDetect` + `EdgeDetect` + `Dilation`

```
ImageMultiply[img, ColorNegate @
  Dilation[EdgeDetect @ ImagePad[ColorNegate @ ContourDetect[img], 20], thickness]]
```

[image]

**2.** `ComponentMeasurements`

```
img0 = ImagePad[img, 10]; 

Show[img0, Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[thickness], Red, 
   MaximalBy[Length @* First] @
    First[Values[ComponentMeasurements[img0, "Contours"]]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This code with leaked images worked better

Answer (score 3):

Using `ImageMesh` and textures is a little more awkward than I expected it to be, but it does the job without needing image manipulation like `EdgeDetect`:

```
img = ImageCrop[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvtRV.png"]];
mesh = ImageMesh[AlphaChannel[img]];
coords = MeshCoordinates[mesh];
mmx = MinMax[coords[[All, 1]]];
mmy = MinMax[coords[[All, 2]]];
texcoords = {Rescale[#[[1]], mmx], Rescale[#[[2]], mmy]} & /@ coords;
g = Graphics[{Thickness[.05], Line[coords], Texture[img], 
  Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcoords]}]
```

[image: with border]

Hopefully the result is satisfactory. You can now rasterize it out using `r = Rasterize[g, RasterSize -> ImageDimensions[img]]`. However you may notice it no longer lines up with the original if you do `ImageCompose[img,{r,0.5}]`. That is due to some irritating quirk of `ImageMesh` and I have not figured out a work around yet.

---

Here's how I managed it using image processing functions:

```
ImageCompose[
 img, (* t controls the thickness *)
 With[{t = 5, dims = ImageDimensions[img]},
  Antialiasing ColorConvert[
    ColorNegate@
     ImageResize[
      ColorReplace[
       Dilation[EdgeDetect@ImagePad[AlphaChannel@img, t], t], 
       Black -> Transparent], dims], "RGB"]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: image padding]

Comment: For the intended purpose, I believe it can meet my need

Comment: Hollow objects do not produce good results. I just tested ...

Comment: You didn't specify that in the question or give a hollow image example. In any case the EdgeDetect one will work, not the textured Polygon.

Comment: Sorry ... After I went to test that I realized the possibilities